# BJT conceptual doubt

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, bias, analysis, biasing

I was given this problem in a problem set. I want to ask what will the voltage at Base when \$ \beta \rightarrow \infty\$.

My answer to the problem - When \$ \beta \rightarrow \infty\$ then width of base would be negligible then collector and emiiter would be nearly short. Also, as \$ I_B\$ would be zero, we can remove the wire EI. So the voltages of collector, emitter and base would be same.

I just want to confirm is my answer right.
[image]

Comment: No, it's not correct. You're told Vbe is 0.7V, not 0. Ib = 0 so what does that tell you?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany If Ib=0, we can remove the wire EI and Ic=Ie.

Comment: You should also be able to write the voltages at E and H with almost no calculation.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany How with almost no calculation?

Comment: The current through R1 is the same as the current through R2, and you know the latter. And you know the voltage at A.

Comment: On two conceptual points ... if beta -> infinity then the base width is zero, so the collector and emitter are short. This is thinking on the wrong level. Base width is for the design of a transistor itself, not the design of a circuit employing a transistor. For that, you need the *behaviour* of a transistor. You're told the behaviour, VBE = 0.7 V. So VBE = 0.7 V.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes I know that. There is some calculation there for me. I thought no calculation means just by glancing at the circuit.

Comment: @Neil_UK So, how should I solve the problem then?

Comment: @AQ Follow Sphero's lead. 'No calculation' in this context means nothing more than the back of an envelope, writing each answer down as it comes. What is the voltage across R2? So what is the current through R2? SO given there's no base current, what's the current in R1? So what's the voltage across R1? So what's the voltage at E&H? What's the voltage at L? What's the current in R3? What's the current in R4? Waht's the voltage on the collector? Just write them down one at a time, using a bit of arithmetic as required for the ratios.

Comment: @Neil_UK So, I_R2 = 0.07mA => I_R1 = 0.07mA => V_L = 10 - 100*0.07 -10*0.07 = 2.3V. So, V_b = 2.3+0.7 = 3V. Also, I_R3 = 2.3/3.3 = 0.67mA = I_R4. Is that right?

Comment: @AQ Sounds like you are on the right track.